# What is launchpad in apt-get error messages?

Tags: apt, software-installation, launchpad

when I do `sudo apt-get update` I get these errors,

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages 404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/adilson/experimental/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/adilson/experimental/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have no idea what launchpad is. what this error is? what this error points to?

How can I remove this error?

Thanks.

Comment: i have tried a lot of questions, and deleted the cache, still this error is showing. sorry

Comment: did you add a ppa?

Comment: i'm sorry i dont know with what ppa is installed!

Comment: Okay, you didn't add a ppa then :)

Comment: @John: Do you have any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`? If so (and they end in `.list`), these files are additional repositories that `apt` can get packages from. One of these is likely to be the [PPA](http://askubuntu.com/a/4987/241580) that is referenced above.

Comment: Yeah there exist 13 files, does deleting these files fix the problem?

Comment: once tried installing wine :)

Comment: @John: Delete the files that mention `adilson` and `experimental`. I don't remember the exact formatting of the names, so I can't give you a file name here.

Comment: well that cleared the error :)

Comment: Ok, good! Now we need to handle the question somehow - we found out what the problem is in the comment, but the question is not so clear that is is a duplicate. And then, we need the anser in the comments in a real answer, but that is useful only after the question is rewritten. And with all this, it will get closed as duplicate anyway. That is just not worth the work, we can just flag it to be closed as "very low quality" or "unclear what you're asking". But then it will stay around closed for long time and with no use. @John If you would just delete it jyourself, that would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP reported in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507287/what-is-launchpad-in-apt-get-error-messages#comment684500_507287) that this problem was solved by instructions provided in [saiarcot895](https://askubuntu.com/users/241580/saiarcot895)'s [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507287/what-is-launchpad-in-apt-get-error-messages#comment685861_507287), which said:

> @John: Delete the files that mention `adilson` and `experimental`. I don't remember the exact formatting of the names, so I can't give you a file name here.

In short, the problem here was solved by removing `.list` files from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

<sup>This *may* be a duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages), though that appears currently to be under dispute.</sup>